# Show picture instead of values with mysql information (gateway)

Tags: php, mysql, gateway

I have a gateway that brings me some information in real time like: temperature, water health and some others. 
With this I have a page in php that brings these results into a simple table with the values. 
Everything is working, but I want something different: depending on the current values, **show an image**.

Example: if the temperature drops below 90 fahrenheit then display the X image.

```
<script>
            function loadlink(){
                $('#updateDiv').load('princ_var_gates.php?unidade=".$unidade."',function () {
                     $(this).unwrap();
                });
            }

            loadlink(); // This will run on page load
            setInterval(function(){
                loadlink() // this will run after every 3 seconds
            }, 3000);
        </script>
        "
    ?>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onbeforeunload = function() {
            $.post("funcoes.php", {funcao : '1',
                                   cod_usuario : <?php echo isset($usuario) ? json_encode($usuario->getCod()) : 0;?>,
                                   cod_gateway : <?php echo isset($codGateways) ? json_encode(implode(", ", $codGateways)) : '';?>,
                                   tela : <?php echo json_encode(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));?>});
    };
</script>
```

Can someone help me? Is there a "programming" for this? If I know the name I can search and understand better. I'm kind of lost!

Thank you very much for helping me!

Comment: there are many ways this could be done but without seeing code it is way too broad as it stands

Comment: @RamRaider ok, I posted. Thanks!

Comment: still too broad. There is no example of the data nor really any code that attempts to process it and generate suitable images..... The data structure and content, to my mind, would help determine the approach to use